# Get Operating System info using PowerShell, change Buildnumber to String

Tags: powershell, replace, powershell-4.0

Currently I am querying my Servers for their operating system like this(it's just a part of my full script):

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | % { $_.Buildnumber }
```

The script out-files everything to a csv where I later on replace all Buildnumbers, for example: I replace 9600 with `Windows Server 2012 R2`.
I can write a script which replaces the 9600 in a .csv, but I need a solution which replaces the buildnumber directly.

I am thinking of something like that:

```
If Buildnumber = 9600 -replace "9600", "Windows Server 2012"
```

So far I had no luck. Also I need to changed value to be written to my .csv file.

I have PowerShell V. 4.0

Comment: `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select Caption` ? Why parse and replace ?

Comment: @sodawillow That's an answer man, go post it as one so the question can be closed, and get some credit for good advise!

Comment: Oh, this helps me as well :) , why don't I see the "Caption" when I query "Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem" ? I thought I can only select the values I see. And yes please post it as answer. I am very glad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select Caption
```

holds what you want.

I know it is there from previous questions, but you can see it all like this :

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *
```